# .htaccess redirect path with or without trailing slash

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Given the following path:
http://www.testsite.com/some/path/

I want to redirect it to
http://www.testing.com/new/stuff/

How can I make .htaccess execute that redirect regardless of whether the path has a trailing slash or not?

### Edit

I've tried this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /some/path(.*) /new/stuff/$1
```

However, it results in the following redirect

http://www.testing.com/new/stuff/?/some/path

Comment: Why is there a **?** there? Do you have some other rules that's causing that?

Comment: This is part of a codeigniter site that adjusts the URL, but the point is I don't want anything showing up after '/stuff/' the '/?/some/path' shouldn't be there. How do I make it do the redirect without appending that on the new path?

Comment: If codeigniter is modifying the URL, then you need to look there, because your `RedirectMatch` is doing what it's supposed to.

Comment: Ok. Disregarding what I've written how can I make redirect from one path to another without appending anything to the new path. I just want it to go to '/new/stuff/' with nothing on the end regardless of what, if anything, comes after '/some/path'

Answer (score 0):

> how can I make redirect from one path to another without appending anything to the new path. I just want it to go to '/new/stuff/' with nothing on the end regardless of what, if anything, comes after '/some/path'

Just remove the `$1` from your `RedirectMatch`'s target. You should also include the `^` for the beginning of the URI:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/some/path(.*) /new/stuff/
```

Comment: Just tried this, and I'm still getting '/?/some/path' added to the end of the new path on the redirect.

Comment: @LoneWolfPR Must be something else going on, it works as intended for me: http://i.stack.imgur.com/0eais.png

Comment: I'm guessing it has to do with some of the codeigniter dependent rules. I might have to find a different way to do this. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @LoneWolfPR have you tried putting the `RedirectMatch` above all the other rules? Does /some/path have an htaccess file in it (which would take precedence)?

Comment: I've tried putting it all over the place. Same result. I had to build the solution into the codeigniter framework instead of using .htaccess. Works fine now.